# C++: Unordered_map.emplace(char,int) not setting the value expected

Tags: c++, hash

I tried using unordered_maps in C++ to create a hashtable. 
I try to write a value of 1 for a char key and see 0 getting written. 
Not sure what I'm missing , any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
       void lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s)
       {
            unordered_map< char, int > hash;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while(i < (int)s.length() && j < (int)s.length())
            {
                 if(hash[s[j]])
                    {
                        hash[s[i]] = 0;
                        cout<<"hash removed"<<hash[s[i]]<<"to char"<<s[i]<<endl;
                        i++;
                    }
                 else
                    {
                        hash.emplace(s[j],1);
                        cout<<"hash added"<<hash[s[j]]<<"to char"<<s[j]<<endl;
                        j++;
                    }
            }
            cout<<"iterating through hash"<<endl;
            int max = 0;
            for(auto &itr : hash)
                {
                    cout<<"hash"<<itr.first<<itr.second<<endl;
                    max++;
                }
           cout<<"max"<<max<<endl;
           return;
         }
      };

      int main(int argc, char **argv)
        {
            Solution s;
            s.lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcade");
            return 0;
        }
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Output I get :

hash added0to chara

hash added0to charb

hash added0to charc

hash added0to chara

hash added0to chard

hash added0to chare

iterating through hash

hashe0

hasha0

hashb0

hashc0

hashd0

max5

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I expect a hash added1to chara , but see a 0 instead!

Comment: This is a good opportunity to step through with the debugger and observe the map after each operation. In addition, `emplace` has a return value that you might find helpful.

Comment: `emplace` does nothing if the key is already in the map. Which it is - you added it as a side effect of `operator[]`. Just do `hash[s[i]] = 1;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - is emplace() just another alternative to hash[s[i]]=x ? Since hash[s[i]] creates an entry for the key anyway.

Comment: `hash[a] = b;` would insert a new key if one doesn't exist, and then assign a new value regardless of whether the key has just been inserted, or already existed with another value. `hash.emplace(a, b);` would insert a new key with given value if one didn't already exist; but would do nothing (and therefore preserve the old value) if the key did already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Igor Tandetnik pointed out the if(hash[s[i]] access was creating a hash entry and since emplace() only creates an entry if it isnt already there , the value was never getting updated.